# Template Field not displaying, should use BoundField? (not working either)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I'm using a Gridview to handle my results vía checkbox and plan to display it in a textField in a ModalPopUp. 
First things first. I wanna handle it and somehow when I use a TemplateField, I don't see any result in my alert. But when I try to use a BoundField, the result does show. I don't know if it is because I can only show a boundField or what I am doing wrong. Here is the code part I'm using for this specific part. Everytime I use a TemplateField it won't work :(

```
<Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="selectedMail" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="Id" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Complete Name" SortExpression="FirstName">
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href='candidato.aspx?key=<%#Eval("Key")%>'>
                     <%# Eval("FirstName") %>
                     <%# Eval("MiddleName") %>
                     <%# Eval("LastName") %>
                     <%# Eval("SecondLastName") %></a>
                    <br />
                    <small><%# GetLabels(Eval("Id").ToString())%></small>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    Total candidates: <asp:Label ID="lblTotalApplicants" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vacancies" SortExpression="">
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# GetVacante(Eval("email").ToString())%> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="Status.Nombre" HeaderText="Status" 
                SortExpression="Status.Nombre" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"  ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Created Date" SortExpression="CreatedDate">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#  Eval("createdDate", "{0:MMMM dd, yyyy. H:mm}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Rating" HeaderText="Rating" SortExpression="Rating" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"  />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("email")%> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

asp.cs here is the backend for it.

```
public void loadEmail(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String compEmail = "";
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvApplicants.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox selectedMail = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("selectedMail") as CheckBox);
                if (selectedMail.Checked)
                {
                    string email = row.Cells[7].Text;
                    compEmail = compEmail+" "+ email;
                }
            }

        }
        string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
        script += compEmail;
        script += "');";
        script += "window.location = '";
        script += url;
        script += "'; }";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Redirect", script, true);
    }
```

Comment: What is happening here when you use a TemplateField?  string email = row.Cells[7].Text;

Comment: Complete empty. Blank on the alert.

Comment: The TemplateField probably makes a container, and your control is within the container.  To find out, you need to do some basic debugging, set a breakpoint and examine row.Cells[7] to find out where your control is within it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not using any control inside your `ItemTemplate` and it doesn't give you the `Text` inside them. You need to use some control inside them i.e. `Label`
Replace the following

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <%# Eval("email")%> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

with this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("email") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and within your checkbox check, replace this

```
string email = row.Cells[7].Text;
compEmail = compEmail+" "+ email;
```

with this

```
Label email = (row.Cells[7].FindControl("Label1") as Label);
compEmail = compEmail + " " + email.Text;
```

It will solve your issue, I've tested it.

Hope it helps. Regards!